# Initialize already created objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm intrested is there any way to initialize with dependencies already created objects?

Suppose I have following class:

```
class MyPage {

  @Autowired LogStorage storage;
  private String applicationId;
  private Date date;

  public MyPage(String applicationId, Date date) {
    this.applicationId = applicationId;
    this.date = date;
  }

  public String render() {
    Collection<Entry> entries = storage.getEntries(applicationId, date);
    // render entries into HTML for example
  }
}
```

I want to split object creation into two phases. First of all, creating object with user provided data (`applicationId` and `date` in this example) and the second is initializing object with Spring DI container dependencies. So I need some sort of initializing already created object. I think client code should look something like this:

```
MyPage p = new MyPage(applicationId, date);
beanFactory.initDependencies(p);

String html = p.render();
```

The client doesn't know (and shouldn't in my case) all the dependencies required by Page object, so I can not provide dependencies explicitly. But I have reference to `BeanFactory` object and can delegate this task to Spring. Is there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(p);
```

Alternative methods autowire and autowireBeanProperties

Keep in mind that it will only set bean properties, so no AOP stuff like interceptors, transactions etc.