# Data switching issue in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a search app (1 search criteria screen, and 1 search result screen) and doesn't require user log in (no user session). When 2 users search at the same time, they get their correct search results. However, the data switching appears when they start clicking on pagination/sorting on that search result screen. If a user 2 clicks on pagination/sorting after a user 1, data result of user 2 switches to a user 1's data result, and a user 2 never got his data result back. 
How can I fix this data switching for a user 2?  Thanks

The backing bean has something like

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SearchController {
   private Criteria criteria;   // search criteria
   private ApplicantWrapperList appWrapperList; // result set

   @Autowired     // Spring 4.0
   IApplicationService appService;

   public String searchAction() {
       appWrapperList = new ApplicantWrapperList(appService.search(criteria));
       return "searchResult";
   }
   // public get and set for criteria
   // public get for ApplicantWrapperList

}
```

The searchResult.xhtml has primeface data table.
    `<p:dataTable id="appTable" var="app" value="#{searchController.appWrapperList}" paginator="true" sortMode="multiple"`

Comment: Add `implements Serializable` for SearchController

Comment: I tried it, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I tried CDI, but still got crossing data '@Named @ViewScoped '

Comment: i forgot to say I use glassfish 4.0.1, JSF 2.2.5, Spring 4.0.1, javax.inject 1, and primefaces 4.0.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Check scope of your beans. See [BalusC answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819460/jsf-2-0-injecting-managed-bean-with-a-different-scope) about similar symptoms.